# Dynamic Servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I'm doing a dynamic web app in JAVA and to recover the password of the app, I implemented an email sending a link with a random token to the especific user, with this token I can get some data.

My doubt is, how can I declare the servlet to be dynamic? How can a servlet can be used by multiples tokens?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly it is not the servlet who is handling your requests dynamically but controllers which are mapped to handle requests to the different endpoints. For most apps one servlet would be more than enough to handle all possible requests and scenarios. I suggest to use Spring framework for dealing with JavaEE staff, as it provides great abstractions on top of JavaEE. Good Spring based registration/confirmation example with tokens is described [here](http://www.baeldung.com/registration-verify-user-by-email).

If you do want to use only javaEE approach I suggest to pass token as request param. And get it on the server like this

```
public void handleRequest(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException {

        String paramValue = req.getParameter("token");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm newbie with web-based java. I'll take look to Spring Framework.

Comment: As I know, to do `req.getParameter("token")` it is needed a input with the name `token`, doesn't need?

Comment: You could find really good Spring MVC examples [here](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/spring-mvc-tutorials/).

Comment: For doing it request should have parameter as this /passwordRestoration?token=asd123 . For example you could send link like this to your client so when client would click it - than appropriate request parameter would be sent to your application.

Comment: I created the servlet /passwordRestoration and did the doGet getting the "token", but it says error404, I can't neither access just the /passwordRestoration by the browser